# Where can I find the videos and materials from Polkadot Decoded 2022?

Tags: polkadot, kusama

https://decoded.polkadot.network/ 2022 had a lot of great speakers to talk about many things relevant to Substrate and Polkadot builders, users, and enthusiasts. It was hosted on the [hopin](https://app.hopin.com/events/polkadot-decoded-2022/reception) platform and we were assured that it would be publicly available for everyone after-the-fact to view.

Answer (score 1):

More will be added over time, but here are a few to start (I will update the answer here as I know of more)

- [Björn Wagner kickoff](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7r_ScrX9Ra4)
- [Official Polkadot YouTube playlist](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLOyWqupZ-WGvcE0HKKnORiFqWNv5onxCf)